# Does the rich snippet have to be present visually on the published page?

Tags: rich-snippets

I installed a Wordpress plugin "All In One Schema.org Rich Snippets." To show rich snippets in search results. When I publish items, it shows a rich snippet area below the article. Can I hide that area and Google will still show rich snippets? Thanks.

Comment: Stephen already answer your question [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/65366/58259), why you're [posting same question again](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101761/can-we-hide-rich-snippets-summary-at-the-end-of-the-post) and again even if it is marked as duplicate recently?. If stephen answer is not useful then you can make comment on it.

Comment: @Goyllo: Sorry I had forgot that I asked it.